# Python- execute SQL queries from list of tables and store results in seperate file for each table name

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to read a file which contains a list of `table_names` and I want to execute a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $TABLE_NAME
```

from each SQL Server database.

The results of which I need to store in a separate `.csv` file.

Can you please help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read data from server and write into csv:

get data from sql:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

mydb = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=Server;"
                      "Database=Database;"
                      "uid=username;pwd=password")

cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = """SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"""
cursor.execute(sql)

row = cursor.fetchall()
```

write data into csv:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline= '') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    a.writerow(["Header 1", "Header 2"])  ## etc
    a.writerows(row)
```

Comment: You need to install pyodbc via pip or manually! it is not included in the default python modules. You may also need to install a proper SQL driver that pyodbc can use.

Answer (score 1):

Give this code a try.

```
import pyodbc 
import csv

# SQL Server Connection settings
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=server;"
                      "Database=dbName;"
                      "uid=User;pwd=password"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = conn.cursor()


inputFile= open("absolute_inputfile_path","w+")
outputDataLocation="absolute_outputfile_path"

# Reading inout file line by line, assuming each line is a table name
line = inputFile.readline()
while line:
    tableName = line
    line = f.readline()
    query = "SELECT * FROM " + str(tableName)

    # Read query data 
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Write to File as CSV
    fileWriter = open(outputDataLocation + "/" + str(tableName), 'w')
    myFile = csv.writer(fileWriter)
    myFile.writerows(rows)
    fileWriter.close()

inputFile.close()
```

Comment: Hi Rohit Kumar , apologies for late response i tried your approach it didnt work